# Create table html as the image

Tags: html

https://jsfiddle.net/tn7rd9sq/

I need create the table of this image:

[image]

```
    <table border='1'>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">text</th>
        <th colspan="2">text</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>text</td>
       <td>text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>other text</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I do not know how to do the part when there are 3  together

Comment: What do you mean 3 together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
td {
  width: 20px;  
  height: 20px;  
}

td.wider {
  width:  60px;
}

tr.taller {
  height: 40px;  
}
```

```html
<table border='1'>
  <tr class="taller">
    <td class="wider" rowspan="3"></td>
    <td colspan="6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```